# JPA - Unable to mark for rollback on PersistenceException

Tags: jpa

Its my first post on this website and I am damn sure that I will get solution to my problem. I am not too good in JPA, so stuck in one issue. Not possible to share the complete code but give you an idea what I am trying to achieve by following example:

```
underOneMethod(){

Person personObj1 = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Select * from Person where smthing..");
personObj1.setFirstName("John");
personObj1 = entityManager.merge(personObj1);
entityManager.flush();

Person personObj2 = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Select * from Person where smthing..");
personObj2.setLastName("Cruz");
personObj2 = entityManager.merge(personObj1);
entityManager.flush();

} // This code throws me exception. I think it will work if I use entityManager.clear() method after first flush call but still it will be good, of someone can me some idea of what is happening in this case and how can it be resolved. Thanks in advance..!
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code cannot even compile, createNamedQuery returns a Query not a Person.  Assuming you call getSingleResult, but still createNamedQuery takes a name not SQL, for that you would need createNativeQuery.

Also, the merge is not required, as you just selected the object, so it is already managed.

Including the exception stack trace and real code woulds help.

Comment: It compiles fine and it returns whatever type of object we want. And YES your point is correct that it will take a NAME not query. I just gave a scenario and its works, if I comment the second part (from person2 till flush call).

Comment: As James pointed out, there is no way that code compiles. Your return type and input parameters are both incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I got the answer long back but didn't get time to response here. Anyways its good time to answer. As already mentioned in my previous comment. I used entityManager.clear() method and it worked. Hope it will be helpful for someone else also..!!

```
underOneMethod(){

Person personObj1 = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Select * from Person where smthing..");
personObj1.setFirstName("John");
personObj1 = entityManager.merge(personObj1);
entityManager.flush();

entityManager.clear();

Person personObj2 = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Select * from Person where smthing..");
personObj2.setLastName("Cruz");
personObj2 = entityManager.merge(personObj1);
entityManager.flush();

}
```